# How much is the Class Imbalance Problem rates?

Tags: classification, dataset, class-imbalance

I'm working on a data set and wanted to know is there a standard rate about Class Imbalance problem or not?

I have 47 samples in Class A and 150 Sample in class B , should I use Class Imbalance Technique or these rates are normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule but you better to use such techniques (SMOTE, sampling etc) and try to obtain **50:50** if you can. 
You can utilize my another [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63842/does-sampling-size-matters-in-multi-classification-model/63846#63846) (just ignore multiclass part).

My suggestion is you should create more samples by synthetic data generators like SMOTE. You have a model with very less observations (197). The model may not fit well thus data generation may help your for that case.

Hope it helps!